# i got database connection problem C# winforms

Tags: c#, database-connection

[image]

### this is the details of the error

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Invalid value for key 'integrated security'.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ConvertValueToIntegratedSecurityInternal(String stringValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ConvertValueToIntegratedSecurity()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Task1.Register.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Register.cs:line 29
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Task1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\
```

i am used the service-based database
i don't what information i need to give you but if you need more info please let me know

Comment: check spelling... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo. "Integrated Security=Ture;"

```
Integrated Security=true
```

+
This [site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) is the best source for connection strings.